# Find Nesting Level In List<> Using Properties

Tags: c#, foreach, nested

I'm trying to build a tree structure with some data that I'm receiving from a service. Unfortunately, I have no control over the structure of the data that I'm receiving. The object is built as such:

```
class Module 
{
     public string ModuleCode {get;set;}
     public string ParentCode {get;set;}
}
```

Basically, I am getting a list of around 200 of these objects and I need to find a way to sort through them and arrange them so that the children are correctly associated with their parents.

I have a working method now which is using foreach loops but it's ugly and is limited to the number of foreach loops that I hard code. I want something that is more dynamic.

```
foreach (var module in moduleList.Where(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ParentCode)))
        {
   //Module Level 1 -- Only uppermost parent modules here
   moduleLevel = 1;
   _highestModuleLevel = _highestModuleLevel < moduleLevel ? moduleLevel : _highestModuleLevel;

   foreach (var module2 in moduleList.Where(x => x.ParentCode == module.ModuleCode))
      {
          //Module Level 2 -- 1st children modules
          moduleLevel = 2;
          _highestModuleLevel = _highestModuleLevel < moduleLevel ? moduleLevel : _highestModuleLevel;

          foreach (var module2 in moduleList.Where(x => x.ParentCode == module1.ModuleCode))
            {
                //Module Level  -- children of the 2nd level modules
                moduleLevel = 3;
                _highestModuleLevel = _highestModuleLevel < moduleLevel ? moduleLevel : _highestModuleLevel;
                //Goes on for however many foreaches I can nest
            }
      }
}
```

}

Like I said, this solution does work, but I really feel there has got to be a more programmatic, cleaner and more efficient way to handle this

Comment: What goes at the root of your tree?

Comment: @DavidG, At the root I'm filtering by modules that have null for ParentCode (x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ParentCode))

Comment: What is the goal? I can't see where you put the objects in a tree...

Comment: @RenéVogt, The end goal is to make a menu out of these unsorted items. I need to create a parent/child relationship for each module so that I can build the menu, I didn't show it for brevity, but I'm actually writing html using Razor for each level. If it makes it more clear, I can include that as well, I just didn't think it was necessary

Comment: have you tried doing this recursively?  That would resolve this for n number of nested objects.

Comment: @ChrisBartlett, I'm in the process of trying to find a recursive structure that works for me now. I'm having trouble getting the "moduleLevel" to not reset when the parent foreach loop moves onto its next item. I'll update the post if/when I figure it out.

Comment: I would make 1 pass at all input modules and arrange them into a tree and then in 2nd pass extract them in the desired order. Do you know how to arrange them into a tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Start With**

The following assumes you have a method that gives you back a flattened list of `Modules`. Also, this is untested - might be typos or bugs... just approximately where I'd start to get you a hierarchical list of `Modules`. Notice that I added `Parent` and `Children` to your `Module` class.

```
class Module 
{
    public Module() 
    {
        this.Children = new List<Module>();
    }

    public string ModuleCode {get; set;}
    public string ParentCode {get; set;}
    public Module Parent {get; set;}
    public List<Module> Children {get; private set;}
}

static void main()
{
    List<Module> moduleList = GetFlattenedModules();
    IDictionary<string, Module> moduleCodeToModule = 
        moduleList.ToDictionary(m => m.ModuleCode);

    foreach (Module module in moduleList)
    {
        if (module.ParentCode != null) 
        {
            module.Parent = moduleCodeToModule[module.ParentCode];
            module.Parent.Children.Add(module);
        }
    }
}
```

**What you get**

What this gets you is your original list, but with each `Module` potentially having children, and potentially having a parent.

**What you probably want**

What you probably really want is a list of top level `Modules` only, and you databind against that thing. This is simple to get, with something like:

```
List<Module> topLevelModules = moduleList.Where(m => m.Parent == null).ToList();
```

Comment: my only reservation is that you're merging the purpose of original `Module` class and new `TreeNode-like` class. If you had a separate `TreeNode` class it would have been cleaner for the requestor. You never know what is the origin of their input classes, they may not want to derive from them etc.

Comment: @Mobigital - true - easy enough to remedy. I was just trying to give the OP a simple place to start.

Comment: kudos for doing the child to parent lookup and utilizing the dictionary in the tree reconstruction!

Comment: @Mobigital - Just paying attention to that big-O :)

Answer (score 0):

At first I would cast the `List<object>` to a `List<Module>`:

```
List<Module> modules = moduleList.Cast<Module>();
```

Then I would create a dictionary to easily access the items by their `ModuleCode`

```
Dictionary<string, Module> codeToModule = modules.ToDictionary(m => m.ModuleCode, m => m);
```

Then I would create a tree out of some `TreeNode` objects:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public Module Module { get; set; }
    public Module Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Module> Children { get; set; }
}

List<TreeNode> flatNodes = modules.Select(m => new TreeNode
                            {
                                Module = m,
                                Parent = m.ParentCode == null ? null : codeToModule[m.ParentCode],
                                Children = modules.Where(cm => cm.ParentCode == m.ModuleCode).ToList();
                            }).ToList();
```

Now you have a flat list of all tree nodes, each of them referencing its parent (if there is one) and having a list of their children.
You can now select the root nodes:

```
List<TreeNode> rootNodes = flatNodes.Where(node => node.Parent == null).ToList();
```

---

You said you need the nesting depth. You could calculate this recursivly now:

```
public int GetDepth(TreeNode current, int depth)
{
    return current.Children.Max(child => GetDepth(child, depth + 1));
}

int depth = rootNodes.Max(node => GetDepth(node, 0));
```

Comment: using clashing `m` lambda variables by the way and then using them to compare `m.ParentCode == m.ModuleCode`

Comment: @MobigItal thanks, fixed it. That's what happens when I write from the top of my head in a hurry just before leaving the office...

Comment: also unfortunately this construct doesn't take advantage of a `Dictionary` in the `modules.Where(....)` area which could become quite slow if you have a lot of modules. Just saying. the other solution where module looks for its parent and adds itself as a child works out better - with included optimization.